# Decoding charset problems?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm new to NodeJs, just making a simple irc bot using 'net' but I set (bot.setEncoding('utf8');) and when I output the socket data it returns � instead of á or é. I already tried using `require('utf8')`, which is not working. I already used `iconv`, same problem. I used `StringDecoder`, but it's the same, when I set Encoding to binary I receive á or é but binary encoding is deprecated.
This is my code:

```
var net = require('net');

bot = new net.Socket();
bot.setEncoding('utf8');
bot.setNoDelay();


//Settings
stt = {
    'server'    : 'chat.freenode.net',
    'port'      : 6667,
    'nick'      : 'NodeJs',
    'name'      : 'zzzz',
    'ident'     : 'zzzz,
   'pass'      : '---'
};

bot.connect(6667, stt.server);

bot.on('connect', function() {
   console.log('Connected to server!');
   setTimeout(function() {
       irc.connect();
   }, 1000);
});

bot.on('data', function(data) {
   console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: Sometimes the `data` event sends a Buffer rather than a String. I don't think that's the problem here for a few reasons, but just in case, maybe try `console.log(data.toString());` to see if that fixes your issue.

Comment: @Trott     console.log('Data output: ' + data.toString()); returns     Data output: #test :�

Comment: Judging from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Relay_Chat#Character_encoding your issue is probably that chat.freenode.net is not sending UTF-8. You may have to look into `iconv-lite` or something like that.

Comment: @Trott I'm not using that server I use another one, I created a simple bot with python and php and I don't have that problems with charsets so I think it's a node net module or something :X

Comment: Your sample code above uses chat.freenode.net so I assumed that's where the � was coming from. I tried creating a Node server that sends `é` and `á` and modified your code above to connect to it. Unsurprisingly, it had no issues. Can you post your python/PHP code to pastebin or something if it's not a million lines long?

Comment: @Trott what version of node you used ? i'm using node -v v4.0.0

php bot -> http://pastebin.com/jQyPZEya

Comment: Your PHP code does not specify an encoding. Depending on what's in your `php.ini` file, that may mean it is using iso-8859-1 or something like that and not utf-8. If so, I don't think Node.js supports iso-8859-1 in core, so I think you are going to have to look into something like `iconv-lite`. Of course, this is me making a lot of guesses. I hope I'm not wasting your time.

Comment: @Trott well thanks for the help I found a way, I will use Encoding('binary'); is the only way I found till now xD